# Avoid duplicate entries in a UITableView in ios

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios5, duplicates

I have developed a application where i have a method that used managed object context of core data framework to load its content to data base. I am calling that method in the did finish launching method of delegate. and I am using a UITableView to fetch the data and displaying it in the table view. My problem is the same data is displaying twice in the table view.
When i launch the application using Xcode the data is displaying only one time and then after stopping the xcode and when i open the application for the first time in the device i am getting the duplicate copy of the same data. I am not getting how to avoid this duplication please help me with this.

```
    -(void) devicedetails
     { 
         devicename = [UIDevice currentDevice].name;
       osversion = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion;
       //some other data like this
       NSManagedObjectContext context = [self managedObjectContext];
      Deviceinfo *detail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Deviceinfo" inManagedObjectContext:nscontext];
      detail.platform = devicename;
      detail.os_version = devosversion;
       .
       .
       .
    }
```

This is my method and i called it in didfinish launching method like below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  { 
    [self devicedetails];
    return YES;
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: I think there is problem with launching since its duplicating only once in when the device is launched in the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting a new object every time you call `-insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`.

What you should do is to try and fetch the object before inserting it. If the fetch is empty then insert the new object, otherwise don't insert it.